# Format int to string with decimals

Tags: c#

I am trying to format a string using `string.Format` method to produce a fixed decimal string from an `int` data type.

I have tried following code :

```
sOutputString = string.Format(
  "Days:{0:D1} Hours:{1:D1} Minutes:{2:D1} Seconds:{3:D1} Miliseconds:{4:D1}",
   objTimeCalculate.Days,
   objTimeCalculate.Hours,
   objTimeCalculate.Minutes,
   objTimeCalculate.Seconds,
   objTimeCalculate.Miliseconds);
```

The values of the properties `Days`, `Hours`, `Minutes`, `Seconds` are `int` data type and formatted using the `D` format specified. However I need `decimal` values produced in the string.

Output should be :

`sOutputString = Days : double_value Hours : double_value Minutes : double_value Seconds : double_value Miliseconds : integer_value`

Since the property days can go beyond reach of the integer datatypes reach.

Comment: Please include your expected output.

Comment: As @Nico has stated. Please give an example of the type of data going in and what you ultimately expect sOutputString to look like.

Comment: Use F or G format.

Comment: Can you explain me how to user F or G? @Paweł Dyl

Comment: See different formats here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `objTimeCalculate` is a `TimeSpan` all those variables are `int`. Therefore they dont have a decimal value.

However we could use the format string `F1` which will return with a fixed decimal value, however this will always be `0`.

Example:

```
var objTimeCalculate =(DateTime.Now - DateTime.UtcNow);

var sOutputString = string.Format(
    "Days:{0:F1} Hours:{1:F1} Minutes:{2:F1} Seconds:{3:F1} Miliseconds:{4:F1}",
    objTimeCalculate.Days,
    objTimeCalculate.Hours,
    objTimeCalculate.Minutes,
    objTimeCalculate.Seconds,
    objTimeCalculate.Milliseconds);
```

Result:

```
Days:0.0 Hours:9.0 Minutes:29.0 Seconds:59.0 Miliseconds:996.0
```

You can consult [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

> "F" or "f" Fixed-point
>
> Result: Integral and decimal digits with optional negative sign.
> Supported by: All numeric types. Precision specifier: Number of
> decimal digits. Default precision specifier: Defined by
> NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits.
>
> [The Fixed-Point ("F") Format Specifier.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#FFormatString)

Comment: The `D` specifier is only for `int` types and does not have an exponential value. You should stick with `F`if you must show the decimal value. Trying to use `D` on anything else than an `int` will result in a Format Exception.

Comment: If I use F I get accurate output but output doesn't look good for a very large number

Comment: If you review the standard format strings you will see there are many other options. If you are looking to add comma separators for large numbers use the `N` format provider.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking F specifier:

```
sOutputString = string.Format(
  "Days:{0:F2} Hours:{1:F2} Minutes:{2:F2} Seconds:{3:F2} Miliseconds:{4:F2}",
   objTimeCalculate.Days,
   objTimeCalculate.Hours,
   objTimeCalculate.Minutes,
   objTimeCalculate.Seconds,
   objTimeCalculate.Miliseconds);
```